# Split <ul> into a <table> and a <ul>

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-table, html-lists

This is what the product details for one of our products look like and is formatted before we import it into Shopify to be shown on our e-com store:

```
<ul>
<li>Comfort: waterproof, windproof, lightweight, engineered ventilation</li>
<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
<li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li>
<li>Fit: Casual unisex</li>
<li>Snap closure</li>
<li>Placket with snap fastenings</li>
<li>Drawstring hood with cap brim</li>
<li>Snap adjustable cuffs</li>
<li>Back yoke with concealed vents</li>
<li>Two side pockets with snaps</li>
<li>Eyelets at arm holes</li>
<li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li>
<li>Fishtail hem</li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to achieve is to convert that ^ into this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td>Comfort:</td>
    <td>waterproof, windproof, lightweight, engineered ventilation</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Material:</td>
    <td>100% polyester with polyurethane coating</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Water column pressure:</td>
    <td>4000mm</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Fit:</td>
    <td>Casual unisex</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<ul>
<li>Snap closure</li>
<li>Placket with snap fastenings</li>
<li>Drawstring hood with cap brim</li>
<li>Snap adjustable cuffs</li>
<li>Back yoke with concealed vents</li>
<li>Two side pockets with snaps</li>
<li>Eyelets at arm holes</li>
<li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li>
<li>Fishtail hem</li>
</ul>
```

The logic behind it: **All lines that has a colon should be in a table format. The rest should be in a list format.**

When the line has a  colon, it should be split into two different columns inside the table. For example,  `<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>` is turned into

```
<tr>
    <td>Material:</td>
    <td>100% polyester with polyurethane coating</td>
  </tr>
```

Can this be automatically done in Google Sheets where each cell contain product details for one product.

Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to look into [The Description List <ul>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl), which is more suited for key-value-pairs than a table—which, btw, would need more semantics, by use of `<th>` for example.

Comment: So you want the resulting HTML to be in a Google Spreadsheet? Why? Where is the data coming from originally and in which format?

Comment: You do not need Google Apps Script nor a Google Spreadsheet to convert your HTML list into a HTML table. A Google Spreadsheet  has nothing to do with an HTML table and does not use any <table> <tr> or <td> tags.

Comment: The reason why I want it to be in a Google Spreadsheet is just because that is where I already have all the product details stored.

Comment: The data is stored in the Google Sheet as unordered lists.

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

Using App script the following example script will take each row and convert any rows that contain `:` into a table.  The end result of this scipt is a single string of all the  and  lines

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let data = `<ul>
<li>Comfort: waterproof, windproof, lightweight, engineered ventilation</li>
<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
<li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li>
<li>Fit: Casual unisex</li>
<li>Snap closure</li>
<li>Placket with snap fastenings</li>
<li>Drawstring hood with cap brim</li>
<li>Snap adjustable cuffs</li>
<li>Back yoke with concealed vents</li>
<li>Two side pockets with snaps</li>
<li>Eyelets at arm holes</li>
<li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li>
<li>Fishtail hem</li>
</ul>`;
    // asuming every line is seperated by a \n new line
    data = data.split('\n');
    let table = [];
    for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      // remove old tags
      if( ( data[i] === '<ul>' ) || ( data[i] === '</ul>' ) ) continue;
      data[i] = data[i].replace("<li>","");
      data[i] = data[i].replace("</li>","");
      // now get lines that are part of a table
      table.push(data[i].split(":"));
    }
    // now add the new tags
    let results = [];
    let newTable = false;
    let newUl = false;
    for( let i=0; i<table.length; i++ ) {
      if( table[i].length > 1 ) {
        if( newUl ) {
          // close out unordered list
          results.push(["</ul>"]);
          newUl = false;
        }
        if( !newTable ) {
          // create new table
          newTable = true;
          results.push(['<table>']);
        }
        // add a row
        results.push(["<td>"+table[i][0]+"</td><td>"+table[i][1].trim()+"</td>"]);
      }
      else {
        if( newTable ) {
          // close out old table
          results.push(["</table>"]);
          newTable = false;
        }
        if( !newUl ) {
          // create new unordered list
          newUl = true;
          results.push(["<ul>"]);
        }
        // add a list item
        results.push(["<li>"+table[i][0]+"</li>"]);
      }
    }
    if( newTable ) results.push(["</table>"]);
    if( newUl ) results.push(["</ul>"]);
    results = results.join(" ");
    console.log(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
7:21:43 AM  Notice  Execution started
7:21:46 AM  Info    <table> <td>Comfort</td><td>waterproof, windproof, lightweight, engineered ventilation</td> <td>Material</td><td>100% polyester with polyurethane coating</td> <td>Water column pressure</td><td>4000mm</td> <td>Fit</td><td>Casual unisex</td> </table> <ul> <li>Snap closure</li> <li>Placket with snap fastenings</li> <li>Drawstring hood with cap brim</li> <li>Snap adjustable cuffs</li> <li>Back yoke with concealed vents</li> <li>Two side pockets with snaps</li> <li>Eyelets at arm holes</li> <li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li> <li>Fishtail hem</li> </ul>
7:21:44 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Hi. It doesnt seem to be working, unfortunately. 

Based on what you are writing, am I meant to be placing each <li> line in its own row in the Google Sheet before running the script? Or can I have the entire set of product details placed in one single cell and then run it? (that is what I would like to do)

Comment: You asked if it could be done in Google Sheets so I assumed you were creating a line for each product in a row of a sheet.  If you are reading raw data from some other source and want it reformatted, let me know.

Comment: It is in Google Sheets. Product details for each product is placed in its own cell and not in separate lines. Thanks. Let me know if it does not make sense.

Comment: I guess I'm unclear as to what the raw data looks like.  I assumed it was as shown in your first code block, each line a row in a spreadsheet.  Including the `<li>` tags.

Comment: <ul>
<li>Comfort: waterproof, windproof, lightweight, engineered ventilation</li>
<li>Material: 100% polyester with polyurethane coating</li>
<li>Water column pressure: 4000mm</li>
<li>Fit: Casual unisex</li>
<li>Snap closure</li>
<li>Placket with snap fastenings</li>
<li>Drawstring hood with cap brim</li>
<li>Snap adjustable cuffs</li>
<li>Back yoke with concealed vents</li>
<li>Two side pockets with snaps</li>
<li>Eyelets at arm holes</li>
<li>Ultrasonically welded seams</li>
<li>Fishtail hem</li>
</ul>

Comment: The above is what the data looks like and it is placed in one cell in Google Sheets and not in seperate rows or cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function transform(input) {
  return (input.replace(/<\/ul>/g, '</table>')
    .replace(/<ul>/g, '<table>')
    .replace(/<\/li>/g, '</td></tr>')
    .replace(/<li>/g, '<tr><td>')
    .replace(/:/g, '</td><td>'))
}
```

[image]